# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'django_markdown' is not a registered tag library

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-markdown-deux

After upgrading django2.1.3 and install 'django_markdown' This error throwing, when I'm going to add any user or to see details from Django admin panel. But I didn't use django_markdown in my project yet.
So what should I do now for this problem?

- 'django_markdown' is not a registered tag library.

  admin_list,
     admin_modify,
   admin_static, 
  admin_urls, 
  cache, 
  i18n,
   l10n,
   log,
     static,
   staticfiles,
   tz

It's showing appears in size.

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question!

Comment: Try adding it in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @dan-klasson Thanks